# Access fully parsed config in typesafe config

Tags: java, scala, config, configuration-files

Given a `appplication.config` which contains fixed values and optional overwrites as for example like this:

```
  timeout.seconds = 30
  timeout.seconds=${?SSO_TIMEOUT_SECONDS}
```

using com.typesafe.config

**which function does return the config with fully parsed entries?**

e.g

```
timeout.seconds = 99
```

if it has been set externally otherwise the default value.
NOT returned should be the config with preset values AND optional replacements.

I tested

```
ConfigFactory.defaultApplication()
```

but that does return both. Although the description makes me think it would not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the default config using

```
ConfigFactory.load()
```

This will replace any substitutions with the appropriate values.